# Scrape using XMLHTTP throws error at specific class name

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a site with this code to extract names and contacts ...

```
Sub Test()
Dim htmlDoc         As Object
Dim htmlDoc2        As Object
Dim elem            As Variant
Dim tag             As Variant
Dim dns             As String
Dim pageSource      As String
Dim pageSource2     As String
Dim url             As String
Dim row             As Long

row = 2
dns = "https://www.zillow.com/detroit-mi/real-estate-agent-reviews/"

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", dns, True
    .send

    While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    If .statusText <> "OK" Then
        MsgBox "ERROR" & .Status & " - " & .statusText, vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    pageSource = .responseText
End With

Set htmlDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = pageSource
```

Dim xx
'Got error here
Set xx = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("ldb-contact-summary")

```
Set htmlDoc = Nothing
Set htmlDoc2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

When trying to use this line

```
Set xx = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("ldb-contact-summary")
```

I got an error 'Object doesn't support that property or method' (438)
Can you help me please as I am not so good at scraping issues?

Comment: Try using `Dim htmldoc As New HTMLDocument` instead of `Set htmlDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")`. So far I knew `.getElementsByClassName()` doesn't support the way you tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the names and their corresponding phone numbers, you can try the below snippet:

```
Sub GetProfileInfo()
    Const URL$ = "https://www.zillow.com/detroit-mi/real-estate-agent-reviews/?page="
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As HTMLDivElement, R&, P&

    For p = 1 To 3 'put here the highest number you wanna traverse
        With Http
            .Open "GET", URL & p, False
            .send
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        For Each post In Html.getElementsByClassName("ldb-contact-summary")
            With post.querySelectorAll(".ldb-contact-name a")
                If .Length Then R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = .item(0).innerText
            End With

            With post.getElementsByClassName("ldb-phone-number")
                If .Length Then Cells(R, 2) = .item(0).innerText
            End With
        Next post
    Next p
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library to execute the above script:

```
Microsoft xml, v6.0
Microsoft Html Object Library
```

Comment: Nice as  usual +

Comment: Glad you liked it. Thanks.

Comment: Another point if possible : How can I loop through the pages (pagination point)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for great help. Best Regards

Comment: You're awesome. Thank you very much for great help

Comment: I am trying to learn how to get the review link and I used `With post.getElementsByTagName("p")(2).getElementsByTagName("a")
                     Cells(r, 3) = .href
                End With` .. How can this be fixed ? Please don't update the code .. Just guide me in comments so as to learn better ..and what if I need to use querySelectorAll in this point?

Comment: How about this `With post.querySelectorAll("a[class^='zsg-link']"): If .Length Then Cells(R, 2) = .item(0).href: End With`? Make a newline removing each colon.

Comment: That's working well but I couldn't get this part 'a.zsg-link' >> a for a Tag Name and I didn't find 'zsg-link' when inspecting .. how did you get this ?

Comment: Using chrome dev tools. Btw, search using `[class^='zsg-link']`. Open the tool, inspect element. Click anywhere within the inspected area, press ctrl+f and paste `[class^='zsg-link']` using ctrl+v. You should find that if you are in chrome. Btw, I've updated the comment with `.querySelectorAll("a[class^='zsg-link']")` selector which you might have noticed already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181975/discussion-between-yasserkhalil-and-sim).

Answer (score 2):

As you mention all the pages in the comment above I will use a class to hold the XMLHTTP object and provide it with methods to extract the data, whilst incorporating a method to find the number of results pages and loop them. Testing this gave me 251 rows of results.

Note: Discovered through debugging that keeping the SetRequestHeader was causing, for you, requests for human verification. Removing this meant the XMLHTTP method worked. It worked with and without for me.

Class clsHTTP

```
Option Explicit    
Private http As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
End Sub

Public Function GetString(ByVal url As String) As String
    Dim sResponse As String
    With http
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
        GetString = sResponse
    End With
End Function

Public Function GetInfo(ByVal html As HTMLDocument) As Variant

    Dim names As Object, telNums As Object, i As Long, namesArray(), telsArray()
    Set names = html.querySelectorAll("[class*='ldb-contact-name']")
    Set telNums = html.querySelectorAll(".ldb-phone-number")

    ReDim namesArray(0 To names.Length - 1)
    ReDim telsArray(0 To telNums.Length - 1)

    For i = 0 To names.Length - 1
        namesArray(i) = names.item(i).innerText
        telsArray(i) = telNums.item(i).innerText
    Next     
    GetInfo = Array(namesArray, telsArray)
End Function
```

Standard module 1

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetReviewData()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, http As clsHTTP
    Dim numPages As Long, pageNum As Long, url As String
    Dim results As Collection, item As Variant, ws As Worksheet

    url = "https://www.zillow.com/detroit-mi/real-estate-agent-reviews/"
    Set http = New clsHTTP
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Set results = New Collection
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With html
        .body.innerHTML = http.GetString(url)           
        numPages = .querySelectorAll("[data-idx]").item(html.querySelectorAll("[data-idx]").Length - 2).innerText            
        results.Add http.GetInfo(html)

        If numPages > 1 Then
            For pageNum = 2 To numPages
                url = "https://www.zillow.com/detroit-mi/real-estate-agent-reviews/?page=" & pageNum & "&showAdvancedItems=false&regionID=17762&locationText=Detroit%20MI"
                .body.innerHTML = http.GetString(url)
                results.Add http.GetInfo(html)
            Next
        End If

        Dim numResults As Long
        If results.Count > 0 Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            For Each item In results
                numResults = UBound(item(0)) + 1
                With ws
                    .Cells(GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 1, 1).Resize(numResults, 1) = Application.Transpose(item(0))
                    .Cells(GetLastRow(ws, 2) + 1, 2).Resize(numResults, 1) = Application.Transpose(item(1))
                End With
            Next
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

---

Selenium:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetReviewData()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Dim numPages As Long, pageNum As Long, url As String
    Dim results As Collection, item As Variant, ws As Worksheet
    Dim d As WebDriver, elements As WebElements

    url = "https://www.zillow.com/detroit-mi/real-estate-agent-reviews/?page=1&showAdvancedItems=false&regionID=17762&locationText=Detroit%20MI"
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Set results = New Collection
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get url

        Set elements = .FindElementsByCss("[data-idx]")
        numPages = elements(elements.Count - 1).Text
        html.body.innerHTML = .PageSource
        results.Add GetInfo(html)

        If numPages > 1 Then
            For pageNum = 2 To numPages

                Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
                url = "https://www.zillow.com/detroit-mi/real-estate-agent-reviews/?page=" & pageNum & "&showAdvancedItems=false&regionID=17762&locationText=Detroit%20MI"
                .get url
                html.body.innerHTML = .PageSource
                results.Add GetInfo(html)
            Next
        End If

        Dim numResults As Long
        If results.Count > 0 Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            For Each item In results
                numResults = UBound(item(0)) + 1
                With ws
                    .Cells(GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 1, 1).Resize(numResults, 1) = Application.Transpose(item(0))
                    .Cells(GetLastRow(ws, 2) + 1, 2).Resize(numResults, 1) = Application.Transpose(item(1))
                End With
            Next
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

Public Function GetInfo(ByVal html As HTMLDocument) As Variant

    Dim names As Object, telNums As Object, i As Long, namesArray(), telsArray()
    Set names = html.querySelectorAll("[class*='ldb-contact-name']")
    Set telNums = html.querySelectorAll(".ldb-phone-number")

    ReDim namesArray(0 To names.Length - 1)
    ReDim telsArray(0 To telNums.Length - 1)

    For i = 0 To names.Length - 1
        namesArray(i) = names.item(i).innerText
        telsArray(i) = telNums.item(i).innerText
    Next

    GetInfo = Array(namesArray, telsArray)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will study it line by line but testing first I encountered an error at this line `numPages = .querySelectorAll("[data-idx]").item(html.querySelectorAll("[data-idx]").Length - 2).innerText`

Comment: Odd... runs fine each time for me and I get 251 results rows. You can try replacing that line with:     Dim ele As Object:
        Set ele = .querySelectorAll("[data-idx]") :
        numPages = ele.item(ele.Length - 2).innerText

Comment: And see if ele is nothing for example.

Comment: The same error `numPages = ele.item(ele.Length - 2).innerText` but ele is [object] so it is not Nothing .. And when trying to see the locals window for ele, excel stopped .. this happened twice

Comment: you can't inspect nodeList within the locals window. It is a bug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181978/discussion-between-qharr-and-yasserkhalil).

Comment: I put a file link in chat.

Comment: Thanks a lot for great and awesome solutions. I have left a message on Chat