# How to make XMLHTTP works on MAC

Tags: excel, vba, macos, web-scraping

I have posted a thread before and it is solved in perfect way at this link
[Scrape using XMLHTTP throws error at specific class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52841969/scrape-using-xmlhttp-throws-error-at-specific-class-name)
 And here is the working code

```
Sub GetProfileInfo()
Const URL$ = "https://www.zillow.com/detroit-mi/real-estate-agent-reviews/?page="
Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
Dim post As HTMLDivElement, R&, P&

For p = 1 To 3 'put here the highest number you wanna traverse
    With Http
        .Open "GET", URL & p, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each post In Html.getElementsByClassName("ldb-contact-summary")
        With post.querySelectorAll(".ldb-contact-name a")
            If .Length Then R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = .item(0).innerText
        End With

        With post.getElementsByClassName("ldb-phone-number")
            If .Length Then Cells(R, 2) = .item(0).innerText
        End With
    Next post
Next p
End Sub
```

But it seems that it works only on windows. How can I get it work on MAC?

Comment: Seems like `HttpRequests` are broken on Office for Mac. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/48600055/9439330 works.Or try a shell with [cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906626/curl-to-return-http-status-code-along-with-the-response)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282443/winhttprequest-on-mac-osx-excel-2011-vba

Comment: @ashleedawg, your possible dupe is 5years old, a long time and it doesn't cover the shell just `QueryTables`. Maybe similar, but a newer look at it will take care of new problems (as ms doesn't care to much on Office on Mac OS).

Comment: @ComputerVersteher - alright. I  wasn't sure, hence why it was a comment, not a flag.

Comment: @ashleedawg, keep on cleaning SO up. I tend to give attention to poor and dupe questions, what I should avoid (but I like to help :( )

Comment: [VBA-Web](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web) looks intersting for Webrequest on Mac.

Comment: Did you ever get a good solution?  I suspect it will involve AppleScript.